# How to exclude jar from Gradle unit testing in Android Studio from build.gradle

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle

In my android studio project, I imported opencsv-3.6.jar as one of module. However, running unit test got the following error:

---

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':opencsv-3.6'.

Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

---

I tried put the exclude in app/build.gradle but failed.

```
configurations {
    testCompile.exclude module: 'opencsv'
}
```

In opencsv-3.6/build.gradle, it is:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('opencsv-3.6.jar'))
```

May I know how to ignore testing this module?